# A question about proving a tautology in set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $A,B,C,D$ are sets,with $A \neq \emptyset $ and $B \neq \emptyset $. Show that if $(A \times B)\cup(B \times A)=(C \times D)\cup(D \times C)$,then either $(A=C) \land (B=D)$ or $(A=D) \land (B=C)$.

I try to negate the first equality,i.e.$(A \neq C) \lor (B \neq D)$  and try to prove that it will lead to $(A=D) \land (B=C)$, however I find it is too difficult to discuss the whole situation. Hope that someone can help me with it.

Comment: Looking at that I believe that you will have a considerable number of cases to deal with

Comment: Notice that $A \cup B = C \cup D$.

Comment: Step 1 : Suppose that $A \neq D$ and proof that $B \subset D$ and $D \subset B$.
Step 2 : Deduce that $A = C$.

Comment: @Essaidi Maybe Step2 you want to say $B=C$?

Comment: No $A = C$. The idea is to suppose that $(A = D) \wedge (B = C)$ is false and to prove that $A = C$ and $B = D$. Without loss of generality we can just suppose that $A \neq D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make your question as an exercise with many questions :
Let $A, B, C, D$ $4$ sets.

1. Show that if :
   $$(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = (C \times D) \cup (D \times C)$$
   then :
   $$A \cup B = C \cup D$$
2. Show that if :
   $$(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = (A \times C) \cup (C \times A)$$
   then $B = C$.
3. Now, suppose that :
   $$(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = (C \times D) \cup (D \times C)$$

   1. Show that if $A \not \subset D$ then $B \subset D$.
   2. Deduce that $B = D$.

   Deduce that :
   $$((A = C) \wedge (B = D)) \text{ or } ((A = D) \wedge (B = C))$$

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks very much. Now, it makes me clearer.